# Change value of inserted row's column with trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to write a trigger with this logic:

After insert, if a certain column = 'Fprice_bat', change the value of a different column to '0000'.

What I have written so far tries to simply add a new record to the table instead of updating the inserted line.

My query looks like this right now.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_FixBatchTimes_I]
ON [dbo].[HEADER_BAT]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE 
        @Starttime varchar(6),                      
        @Endtime varchar(6),                        
        @Batchstate varchar(30),                    
        @Batchtype varchar(30)                                                      

    SELECT
        @Starttime = F908,                          
        @Endtime = F910,                            
        @Batchstate = F914,                         
        @Batchtype = F916   
    FROM 
        inserted

    IF @Batchtype = 'FSPRICE_BAT'  
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO HEADER_BAT (F908, F910, F914)
        VALUES (0000, 2359, 'WAIT')
    END
```

I imagine my mistake is because I'm calling "Insert into header_Bat" and it should say something along the lines of insert into inserted... but that syntax isn't right.

How do I make this query edit the inserted line instead of add a new record to the table?

Comment: change it to a `before` trigger. you can modify the values BEFORE they're inserted into the table.

Comment: use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger

Comment: `if a certain field = 'Fprice_bat' change the value of a different field to '0000' ` Inserts do not change any values they simply insert new records, Your question doesn't make much sense to me. Could you please explain it a bit more clearly.

Comment: Also, your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. It assumes there will only ever be a single row in inserted. In sql server triggers fire once per operation, not once per row. You need to make your triggers set based. When you use scalar variables and then make a decision you are creating bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first mistake is to assume single row insert only. All DML operations are **set** operations. So if you want to update something work with sets.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_FixBatchTimes_I]
    ON  [dbo].[HEADER_BAT]
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    update HEADER_BAT
      set F908='0000', F910=2359, F914='WAIT'
    from HEADER_BAT h
         inner join inserted i on h.id = i.id --or what is PK
    where i.F916 = 'FSPRICE_BAT'
END
```

Comment: This looked like it worked. I'm pretty sure I follow your logic too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand your logic but I think you wanted to change the value being inserted in `F908` column depending on what is being passed in the `F916` column.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_FixBatchTimes_I]
ON  [dbo].[HEADER_BAT]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO HEADER_BAT (F908, F910, F914)
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN F916 = 'FSPRICE_BAT' THEN '0000' ELSE F908 END
       ,F910  -- Hardcode the value to 2359 or use from inserted
       ,F914  -- Hardcode the value to 'WAIT' or use from inserted
    FROM inserted
END
```